# I have questions about "to put on the runway" meaning in this text

Tags: word-meaning

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.
>
> Much of what Maccari  **put on the runway**  might actually have been better appreciated in a more intimate setting where audience members are able to put their hands on the fabric, see the details up close. But **putting Perry Ellis on the runway** during the inaugural season of New York Fashion Week: Men’s, served a larger purpose. It sent a message: This, too, is fashion. And there’s nothing to fear.

1. What does the word **runway** refer to in previous sentences?
2. Is **to put on the runway** an idiom? What is its meaning?
3. And the most important question: What is the difference between meaning of **what the manager of the company put on the runway** and **put the company on the runway** ?

Comment: Given the context, I find it hard to believe OP would be unable to find the relevant sense of ***runway*** in the fashion world (though in fact it's more often called the ***catwalk*** by people in general). The other aspects of this question seem equally basic.

Answer (score 1):

1) Fashion shows normally have a path that the models walk. This is traditionally called a runway.

[image]

<sub>From http://www.zimbio.com/photos/Carlson/iD+Dunedin+Fashion+Show+Runway/OLkdx5v77_K</sub>

2) In a given season a fashion designer will produce many designs, but will not try for maximum publicity for most of them. Those that are exhibited at fashion shows (worn by models) are "put on the runway".

3) EDIT - To put a company on the runway means the fashion show producers decide to include fashions from that company. In other words, those who control fashion decide that the company's products meet their standards. Fashion shows are not open to anyone who thinks of himself or herself as a designer - inclusion is by invitation only.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I just highlighted the part related to third question.

Comment: I think I got it. It has the same meaning